# Understanding the struts2 configuration file

Tags: struts

The below piece of code was written in struts-config file.but i am not able to understand it.

```
   <action path="/showWelcome"
            type="com.code.base.presentation.struts.actions.StrutsIoCAction"
            name="LoanDetailPageLoadForm"
            parameter="GET_WELCOME_PAGE"
            input="welcomePage"
            validate="false"
            scope="request">
        <set-property property="requestDTOKeyName" value="ItemDataRequest" />
        <set-property property="responseDTOKeyName" value="ItemDataResponse" />
        <set-property property="exceptionDTOKeyName" value="ProfileSekerException" />

        <set-property property="businessServiceId" value="ItemsDataMgmtService" />

        <forward name="success" path="welcomePage" />
        <forward name="failure" path="sysError" />
    </action>
```

My question is

1. what is the usage of `path` attribute?
2. what is the usage of `parameter` attribute?
3. what is the usage of `input` attribute?
4. what is the usage of `<set-Property>`?

Help me guys on this.

Note:
  as per my understanding there should be "showWelcome.jsp" page in the application but it is not there.(then what is use of that?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It specifies where the action is mounted. For example, this action would respond on http://yourservice.dom/showWelcome.
2. Parameter is the string you get by calling ActionMapping.getParameter(). Any string you want to pass to your action.
3. Input is a path where the user would be redirected if he fills the form incorrectly. As there's validate=false, I'd say that would never happen.
4. Obviously, it sets a property on com.code.base.presentation.struts.actions.StrutsIoCAction. I think it calls setter, i.e. it would call setRequestDTOKeyName(), setResponseDTOKeyName() etc.

But if you're going to use struts for a considerable time, QA won't get you far, read some docs on struts' config file.

Comment: could you give me some more explanation on 1st point.(ie. showWelcome )..is it need to create showWelcome.jsp page ?

Answer (score 0):

Following on from @Alamar's response...

**There is no showWelcome.jsp**. "/showWelcome" is the URL, but that does not correspond to the name of any actual filename on the server. If this action's configuration contained a line like this:

```
<forward name="success" path="showWelcome.jsp" />
```

Then it would mean that if the action class (StrutsIoCAction) returns success, a file called showWelcome.jsp would be executed. However, as you can see, the actual configuration is a forward to "welcomePage", which is probably not a file but instead the name of another action (also defined in struts-config).

Note: "forward" just means that execution is passed to this other action, it does *not* mean that the user is redirected to another URL.